# How to stop a spring integration process

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration xml file as below: I want to introduce a new mechanism to stop the running process whenever needed by the user. How do I include the mechanism below:

```
    <integration:gateway id="inputGateway"
                         service-interface="com.service.integration.gateways.inputGateway"
                         default-request-channel="inputGatewayChannel"/>
    <integration:channel id="inputGatewayChannel">
        <integration:queue capacity="1000"/>
    </integration:channel>
    <integration:service-activator id="ServiceActivatorA" input-channel="inputGatewayChannel" ref="initiateService" method="process"  output-channel="cleanUpServiceChannel" />
    
    <integration:channel id="cleanUpServiceChannel"/>
    <integration:service-activator id="ServiceActivatorB" input-channel="cleanUpServiceChannel" ref="processService" method="process"  output-channel="luceneIndexReBuilderChannel" />
    
    <integration:channel id="luceneIndexReBuilderChannel"/>
    <integration:service-activator id="luceneIndexReBuilderServiceActivator" input-channel="luceneIndexReBuilderChannel" ref="cleanUpLuceneIndexBuilderService" method="process"  output-channel="completeChannel"/>
    
    <integration:channel id="completeChannel"/>
    <integration:service-activator id="cleanCardPullCompleteServiceActivator" input-channel="completeChannel" ref="completeService" method="processFinalStep"/>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "stop"; there are no active components in that flow; all messaging is driven by calls to the `inputGateway`

Comment: A process triggered by this flow. This process has to be stopped.  Every time message is passed to the next channel, the method gets executed. I mean this process.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess over here because your question is not clear. Please, clarify what exactly you'd like to stop.

But let's assume you start some long process with that flow and you'd like to interrupt it via some end-user hook.

So, consider to have an `AtomicBoolean` bean the state of which could be checked from time to time in your long process to interrup and can be changed externally by end-user. It can be done also per message where you store such an `AtomicBoolean` in the headers and check and change it same way as I explained before. Only the problem here that your long process should consult with such a state. Otherwise it cannot be stopped. Even we `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I mean the process is the messaging process that is  started when the inputGateway is invoked in the code.

Comment: Right. So my answer with a Boolean state is exactly for you. Anything wrong with that ?